# concurrency issue when implementing a simple httprequest queue for android app

Tags: java, android, concurrency, request, queue

I have a problem when I try to implement a queue for http requests from scratch. Sorry, this might be a very naive concurrency problem to someone.

Basically I want my application to execute only one request at any time. Extra requests go into queue and execute later.

I am aware of other advanced stuff such as FutureTask and Execution pool, but I want the answer because I am curious about how to solve the basic concurrency problem. Following is my Class maintains the requestQueue

```
private Queue<HttpRequest> requestQueue;
private AsyncTask myAsyncTask=null;

public boolean send(HttpRequest hr){
   //if there isn't existing task, start a new one, otherwise just enqueue the request
   //COMMENT 1.
   if(myAsyncTask==null){
     requestQueue.offer(hr);
     myAsyncTask= new RequestTask();
     myAsyncTask.execute(null);
     return true;
   }
   else{
     //enqueue
     //COMMENT 2
     requestQueue.offer(hr);
   }

}

//nested class
RequestTask extends AsyncTask<boolean,void,void>{
      protected HttpResponse doInBackground(void... v){
           //send all request in the queue
           while(requestQueue.peek != null){
              HttpResquest r= requestQueue.poll
              //... leave out code about executing the request
           }
           return true;
      }

      protected void doPostExecute(boolean success){


           //COMMENT 3: if scheduler stop here just before myAsyncTask is set to null
           myAsyncTask=null;

      }
}
```

The question is, if thread scheduler stops the background thread at the point COMMENT 3 (just before the myAsyncTask is set to null).

```
      //COMMENT 3: if scheduler stop here just before myAsyncTask is set to null
       myAsyncTask=null;
```

At the time, other threads happen to go to the point COMMENT 1 and go into the if ... else ... block. Because the myAsyncTask have not be set to null, the task get enqueued in else block(COMMENT 2) but new asyncTask will not be created, which means the queue will stuck!

```
   //COMMENT 1.
   if(myAsyncTask==null){
     requestQueue.offer(hr);
     myAsyncTask= new RequestTask;
     myAsyncTask.execute(null);
     return true;
   }
   else{
     //enqueue
     //COMMENT 2
     requestQueue.offer(hr);
   }
```

I hope it is clear. There is a chance that the queue stop being processed. I am keen to know how to avoid this. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would normally implement something like this is to create a class that extends thread. This would contain a queue object (use whichever one you prefer) and would have methods for adding jobs. I'd use synchronization to keep everything thread safe. Notify and wait can be used to avoid polling.

Here's an example that might help...

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class JobProcessor extends Thread
    {
       private Queue queue = new LinkedList();

       public void addJob(Object job)
       {
           synchronized(queue)
           {
              queue.add(job);
              queue.notify(); // lests the thread know that an item is ready
           }
       }


       @Overide
       public void run()
       {
          while (true)
          {
              Object job = null;

              synchronized(queue) // ensures thread safety
              {
                 // waits until something is added to the queue.
                 try
                   while (queue.isEmpty()) queue.wait();
                 catch (InterruptedException e)
                   ; // the wait method can throw an exception you have to catch.
                 // but can ignore if you like.

                 job = queue.poll();
              }
              // at this point you have the job object and can process it!
              // with minimal time waiting on other threads.
              // be sure to check that job isn't null anyway!
              // in case you got an InterruptedException.

              ... processing code ...

              // job done loop back and wait for another job in the queue.
          }
       }
    }
```

You pretty much just have to instantiate a class like this and start the thread, then begin inserting objects to process jobs. When the queue is empty the wait causes this thread to sleep (and also temporarily releases the synchronization lock), notify in the addJob method wakes it back up when required. Synchronization is a way of ensuring that only one thread has access to the queue. If you're not sure about how it works look it up in the java SDK reference.

Your code doesn't have any thread safety code in it (synchronization stuff) and that's where your problem is. It's probably a little over complicated which won't help you debug it either. But the main thing is you need to add synchronization blocks, but make sure you keep them as short as possible.

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of the synchronized blocks, but I think that can not solve the problem in my code. What is new to me in your code is the keywords notify and wait. I am using a flag (AsyncTask==null?) in my code, instead I need to try notify and wait, thank you again:)

Comment: If you're not keen on using synchronized blocks there is a special queue that deals with thread safety in java.util.concurrent called ConcurrentLinkedQueue that will ensure you don't get race conditions on access to the queue anyway

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I investigated synchronized blocks and I think you are indeed right. just one more question, I think it may be necessary to also put a sychronized block on "if (queue.isEmpty()) queue.wait()" in your code, . Assume Thread 1 reaches "if (queue.isEmpty())" (and it is true). just before calling  "queue.wait();", Thread 2 calls "addjob()" and the call returns before "queue.wait();" in Thread 1 executed. Then "queue.notify()" will take no effect because Thread 1 have not called "queue.wait();". when the Thread 1 begin to wait(), the last job will stuck in the queue.

Comment: Ah yes you are technically correct there, another synchronized block there is a good idea. Note that the wait method releases the synchronization until the thread is restarted. I'll edit the code to show you how that should work.

Comment: Hmmm, your note leaves me another question. if put both notify and wait in synchronisation block. It seems to me that it is a dead lock. if one thread begin to wait, no other thread can call notify.

Comment: Your answer made me think a lot more, it is a good one. You are so nice.

Comment: Thats ok :-). To answer the question of deadlock on the notify and wait, this doesn't happen as wait releases the lock until notify reactivates the thread.